# requirejs-rails AMD error "two many anonymous modules in it"

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-4, amd, requirejs-rails

Attempting to precompile my Backbone assets using requirejs-rails (using Rails 4). I keep hitting a roadblock that require-js complains that

```
Error: Error: application.js has two many anonymous modules in it.
```

This appears to be a RequireJS error. Googling finds [this Github issue](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl/issues/42), which I don't understand.

I did discover that the problem lies in any libraries that have AMD conditionals at the head like the example below. I imagine it has something to do with registering itself as an anonymous module. If I remove these conditionals then requirejs-rails no longer complains and I can compile the optimized file which then works within Rails.

But manually removing these AMD conditionals from all my external libraries is not sustainable.

Anyone have a better suggestion? My *requirejs.yml* file is properly setup.

**Note**: I'm using [this fork](https://github.com/scalient/requirejs-rails) of requirejs-rails since the main code does not work with Rails 4.

*As an aside:* I'm able to use the same code without removing the AMD bits in a non-Rails application calling r.js directly (instead of requirejs-rails) to optimize the code. I'm not sure why requirejs-rails' optimization is tripping up on this error when r.js did not. I thought requirejs-rails is calling r.js underneath?

**Example of what is causing the error:**

```
(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define( [ "jquery" ], function ( $ ) {
        factory( $, root, doc );
        return $.mobile;
    });
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory( root.jQuery, root, doc );
}
}( this, document, function ( jQuery, window, document, undefined ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I discovered how to get around this particular problem. The issue lies in the version of r.js that's bundled with the requirejs-rails gem. When I swapped out the v2.1.2 r.js located in .bundler/ruby/2.0.0/requirejs-rails-e0932125e1d5/bin/ with the v2.1.10 located [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#rjs) I no longer received the "two many anonymous modules" error and was eventually able to build the optimized application.js file.

That being said, I eventually ran into more issues related to the requirejs-rails operation. One look at the [requirejs-rails Issues page](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/issues) and you can see there are some resourcing issues with the project. I will likely be abandoning Requirejs for my Rails project - someone has yet to find an elegant solution for working with the Rails 4 asset pipeline.